# How to add methods from enum keys to class in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm rewriting existing code to TS and got such a question:

```js
enum MyEnum { foo = ‘foo’ }

class MyClass {
  // how to add methods declarations here?
}

for (let name in MyEnum)
  MyClass.prototype[name] = () => console.log(MyEnum[name])

const a = new MyClass()
a.foo() // outputs "foo"
```

All methods should have same signature.

Here is what exactly I'm trying to do: it is a package for db migrations (https://www.npmjs.com/package/rake-db) and I'm rewriting it to typescript.

Example usage:

```js
exports.change = (db, up) => {
  db.createTable('entities', (t) => {
    t.text('name')
    t.float('floatColumn') // here is where this enum is needed
    t.timestamps()
  })
}
```

I have enum which maps common types to db specific:

```js
export type ColumnTypes {
  integer = 'integer', // the same
  float = 'float8', // different
  etc = 'etc',
}
```

And I have class which adds columns to database:

```js
class Table {
  column(name: string, type: string, options: ColumnOptions) {}
}
```

I wish it to have typed column methods like:

```js
class Table {
  column(name: string, type: string, options: ColumnOptions) {}

  integer(name: string, options: ColumnOptions) {
    this.column(name, ColumnTypes.integer, options)
  }

  // and other method
}
```

And the reason why I want to dynamically add methods from enum is that with copypasting it takes many-many lines of code in that class, and if I will add new type to enum I have to remember to add corresponding method to class.

Comment: Your enum declaration has two syntax errors. Did you mean to use a string enum and write `enum MyEnum {foo = 'foo'}` or simply `enum MyEnum {foo}` for a numeric enum? Also, are you sure you absolutely need to list the methods in an enum? Because that's about the most complicated way to tell `MyClass` about its methods.

Comment: Sorry, I make mistakes every time I posting to stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

This solution works if all the methods are the same

```
enum MyEnum {
  foo = 'foo',
  test = 'test',
}

type TMyClass = {
  [key in MyEnum]: () => void;
}

class MyClass { }

for (let name in MyEnum) {
  MyClass.prototype[name] = () => console.log(MyEnum[name])
}

const a: TMyClass = new MyClass() as any;

a.foo();
a.test();
```

Comment: Three problems with this: 1 - it's not a solution to cast class instance to different type; 2 - typescript error when setting to prototype here; 3 - if class has 'bar' method then it is not accessible as `a.bar()`

Answer (score 0):

I'd write your DB migration example as follows:

```
const typeMapping = {
  integer: 'integer',
  'float': 'float8',
  // and so on
}

export type ColumnType = keyof typeof typeMapping;

export class Table {
  column(name: string, type: ColumnType, options: ColumnOptions) {
    const dbType = typeMapping[type];
    // your code goes here
  }
}
```

This way, you mention each `columnType` exactly once while retaining full compile time type safety - and yes, callers get code completion for the column type.

The preceeding solution assumes that your column method takes the same parameters for all types. If you want separate methods due to having separate argument lists, you could turn it onto its head as follows:

```
 class Table {
   integer(name: string) {
     // implementation omitted
   }

   decimal(name: string, length: number, precision: number) {
     // implementation omitted
   }
}

const typeMapping: {[T in keyof Table]: string} = {
  integer: 'integer',
  decimal: 'float',
}
```